# How to change dependency manager from Cocoapod to SPM in GitlabCI?

Tags: cocoapods, swift-package-manager, mobile-development

For previous application that I developed, I use cocoapod as Depedencies manager. And for Continuous Delivery I use Fastlane + GitlabCI.

In `gitlab-ci.yml` on `before script` section, I run `pod install` for get all libraries before build.

But I have no idea how to do it with Swift package manager. Do I have to run any command for install library ?